# Artillery not launching scenarios

Tags: performance-testing, nodejs-server, artillery

I'm running my node server on `http://localhost:5000` and wanted to do a performance test using artillery.

Here is my `yaml` file:

```
config:
  target: http://localhost:5000
phases:
- duration: 20
  arrivalRate: 3
  name: Warm up
scenarios:
- name: Test1
  flow:
  - post:
      url: /give
      json:
        item:
          'name': 'book'
          'price': '4.99'
        total:
          'cost': '7.56'
```

But I'm getting this result (seems like test didn't run at all)

```
Elapsed time: 0 seconds
  Scenarios launched:  0
  Scenarios completed: 0
  Requests completed:  0
  Mean response/sec: NaN
  Response time (msec):
    min: NaN
    max: NaN
    median: NaN
    p95: NaN
    p99: NaN

All virtual users finished
Summary report @ 15:48:49(+0530) 2021-07-07
  Scenarios launched:  0
  Scenarios completed: 0
  Requests completed:  0
  Mean response/sec: NaN
  Response time (msec):
    min: NaN
    max: NaN
    median: NaN
    p95: NaN
    p99: NaN
  Scenario counts:
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I made mistake in writing yaml file, `phases` should be inside `config`

```
config:
  target: http://localhost:5000
  phases:
  - duration: 20
    arrivalRate: 3
    name: Warm up
scenarios:
- name: Test1
  flow:
  - post:
      url: /give
      json:
        item:
          'name': 'book'
          'price': '4.99'
        total:
          'cost': '7.56'
```